# Swift: Performing a segue when a variable reaches a certain value

Tags: ios, swift, segue

I'm trying to segue to another view controller once a counter connected to a NSTimer reaches 0.

Heres my timer code:

```
    var counter = 15
    var timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1, target: self, selector: "timerAction", userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

    func timerAction() {
        --counter
        timerLabel.text = "\(counter)"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you've got a segue set up in the storyboard with identifier `mySegueID`, use this code:

```
private var timer:NSTimer! //Make sure this is a property of your class

func timerAction() {
    --counter
    timerLabel.text = "\(counter)"
    if (counter == 0) {
        timer.invalidate()
        timer = nil
        performSegueWithIdentifier("mySegueID", sender: nil)
    }
}
```

This will check if the counter is equal to zero. When it is, it'll stop your `NSTimer` from firing and call the segue that you've set up in your storyboard.

Comment: Worked perfectly, Thank you!

Comment: @Ryan.H Awesome, please mark my answer as correct :)

Answer (score 0):

To trigger the segue, just call the appropriate method when the timer executes.

To be more specific, your timer method could be rewritten. It seems you just want to wait for 15 seconds and then fire the segue, but your code does this by decrementing a counter once a second; a better way is to fire the method after the delay; which you can do more elegantly using GCD:

```
let delay = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, 15 * Int64(NSEC_PER_SEC))
dispatch_after(delay, dispatch_get_main_queue()) { () -> Void in
    performSegueWithIdentifier("mySegueID", sender: nil)
}
```